How to solve CMake Errors
I tried to install opencv in Ubuntu 20.04 - not install libopencv.
I want to install opencv with CUDA support.
I installed CUDA-12.4, CUDNN-9.0.0.
Then I tried to build opencv-4.8.0 using these commands:
test -e 4.8.0.zip || wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/refs/tags/4.8.0.zip
test -e opencv-4.8.0 || unzip 4.8.0.zip
test -e opencv_extra_4.8.0.zip || wget -O opencv_extra_4.8.0.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/refs/tags/4.8.0.zip
test -e opencv_contrib-4.8.0 || unzip opencv_extra_4.8.0.zip

cd opencv-4.8.0
mkdir build
cd build

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D WITH_TBB=ON \
-D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
-D WITH_CUDA=ON \
-D BUILD_opencv_cudacodec=ON \
-D WITH_CUDNN=ON \
-D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON \
-D WITH_QT=OFF \
-D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
-D BUILD_opencv_apps=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
-D OPENCV_PC_FILE_NAME=opencv.pc \
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib-4.8.0/modules \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D WITH_FFMPEG=ON \
-D CUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/cuda/include \
-D CUDNN_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so \
..

make -j$(nproc)

I ran the 'cmake' command and finished successfully.
But when I run the 'make' command I have the errors. The first error is:
[ 25%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/median_blur.dispatch.cpp.o
/opencv_contrib-4.8.0/modules/cudev/include/opencv2/cudev/grid/detail/reduce.hpp(379): error: no instance of overloaded function "cv::cudev::blockReduce" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (cuda::std::__4::tuple<volatile int *, volatile int *>, cuda::std::__4::tuple<int &, int &>, int, cuda::std::__4::tuple<cv::cudev::minimum<int>, cv::cudev::maximum<int>>)
              blockReduce<BLOCK_SIZE>(smem_tuple(sminval, smaxval), tie(mymin, mymax), tid, make_tuple(minOp, maxOp));
              ^
/opencv_contrib-4.8.0/modules/cudev/include/opencv2/cudev/block/reduce.hpp(72): note #3327-D: candidate function template "cv::cudev::blockReduce<N,P0,P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9,R0,R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8,R9,Op0,Op1,Op2,Op3,Op4,Op5,Op6,Op7,Op8,Op9>(const thrust::THRUST_200301_500_520_600_610_700_750_800_860_890_900_NS::tuple<P0, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9> &, const thrust::THRUST_200301_500_520_600_610_700_750_800_860_890_900_NS::tuple<R0, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9> &, uint, const thrust::THRUST_200301_500_520_600_610_700_750_800_860_890_900_NS::tuple<Op0, Op1, Op2, Op3, Op4, Op5, Op6, Op7, Op8, Op9> &)" failed deduction
  __attribute__((device)) __inline__ __attribute__((always_inline)) void blockReduce(const tuple<P0, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9>& smem,
                                                                         ^
/opencv_contrib-4.8.0/modules/cudev/include/opencv2/cudev/block/reduce.hpp(63): note #3327-D: candidate function template "cv::cudev::blockReduce<N,T,Op>(volatile T *, T &, uint, const Op &)" failed deduction
  __attribute__((device)) __inline__ __attribute__((always_inline)) void blockReduce(volatile T* smem, T& val, uint tid, const Op& op)
                                                                         ^
          detected during:
            instantiation of "void cv::cudev::grid_reduce_detail::MinMaxReductor<cv::cudev::grid_reduce_detail::both, src_type, work_type>::reduceGrid<BLOCK_SIZE>(work_type *, int) [with src_type=uchar, work_type=int, BLOCK_SIZE=256]" at line 412
            instantiation of "void cv::cudev::grid_reduce_detail::reduce<Reductor,BLOCK_SIZE,PATCH_X,PATCH_Y,SrcPtr,ResType,MaskPtr>(SrcPtr, ResType *, MaskPtr, int, int) [with Reductor=cv::cudev::grid_reduce_detail::MinMaxReductor<cv::cudev::grid_reduce_detail::both, uchar, int>, BLOCK_SIZE=256, PATCH_X=4, PATCH_Y=4, SrcPtr=cv::cudev::GlobPtr<uchar>, ResType=int, MaskPtr=cv::cudev::WithOutMask]" at line 421
            instantiation of "void cv::cudev::grid_reduce_detail::reduce<Reductor,Policy,SrcPtr,ResType,MaskPtr>(const SrcPtr &, ResType *, const MaskPtr &, int, int, cudaStream_t) [with Reductor=cv::cudev::grid_reduce_detail::MinMaxReductor<cv::cudev::grid_reduce_detail::both, uchar, int>, Policy=cv::cudev::DefaultGlobReducePolicy, SrcPtr=cv::cudev::GlobPtr<uchar>, ResType=int, MaskPtr=cv::cudev::WithOutMask]" at line 460
            instantiation of "void cv::cudev::grid_reduce_detail::minMaxVal<Policy,SrcPtr,ResType,MaskPtr>(const SrcPtr &, ResType *, const MaskPtr &, int, int, cudaStream_t) [with Policy=cv::cudev::DefaultGlobReducePolicy, SrcPtr=cv::cudev::GlobPtr<uchar>, ResType=int, MaskPtr=cv::cudev::WithOutMask]" at line 206 of /opencv_contrib-4.8.0/modules/cudev/include/opencv2/cudev/grid/reduce.hpp
            instantiation of "void cv::cudev::gridFindMinMaxVal_<Policy,SrcPtr,ResType>(const SrcPtr &, cv::cudev::GpuMat_<ResType> &, cv::cuda::Stream &) [with Policy=cv::cudev::DefaultGlobReducePolicy, SrcPtr=cv::cudev::GpuMat_<uchar>, ResType=int]" at line 349 of /opencv_contrib-4.8.0/modules/cudev/include/opencv2/cudev/grid/reduce.hpp
            instantiation of "void cv::cudev::gridFindMinMaxVal(const SrcPtr &, cv::cudev::GpuMat_<ResType> &, cv::cuda::Stream &) [with SrcPtr=cv::cudev::GpuMat_<uchar>, ResType=int]" at line 68 of /opencv_contrib-4.8.0/modules/cudaarithm/src/cuda/minmax.cu
            instantiation of "void <unnamed>::minMaxImpl<T,R>(const cv::cuda::GpuMat &, const cv::cuda::GpuMat &, cv::cuda::GpuMat &, cv::cuda::Stream &) [with T=uchar, R=int]" at line 92 of /opencv_contrib-4.8.0/modules/cudaarithm/src/cuda/minmax.cu

Complete log could be found on the link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/199fYgRktP9vVPVaI4ISuPefPLdR8wkw9/view?usp=sharing
Does anybody have the same problem before? How to fix the problem.
I followed the instruction of https://github.com/cyrusbehr/YOLOv8-TensorRT-CPP/blob/main/README.md

I had the same problem during OpenCV compilation on the x86 platform with CUDA support enabled. I found that there is an incompatibility issue between OpenCV and CUDA 12.4 as mentioned on the GitHub issue CUDA 12.4 is not supported yet, downgrade to CUDA 12.3.
